# What are user-controlled namespaces?

Tags: python, namespaces, magic-methods

Referring to [Python PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__` : "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`,
>   `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

I browsed through many questions related to the use of underscores in Python and I think I have understood the answers to most of them (things like `private` attributes, `name mangling`, etc.). I think I have also understood the aforementioned use of double leading and trailing underscores. I guess it's for protecting functions like `__init__` which are similar to constructors in languages like C++ and Java.

But then shouldn't it be called `community-controlled namespaces` (by community I mean the Python community)? What does the author mean when he says `user-controlled namespaces`? In fact it seems the intent is the opposite: users should not (normally) trifle with these namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-controlled namespaces means namespaces where a user, programming in Python, controls what names exist and what values they have.  In other words, basically user-created APIs.  What it means is that you shouldn't design an API that relies on new `__doubleunderscore_names__` that you make up.

"Namespace" here does not refer to the naming *convention* but to the actual programming scope.  For instance, each function has a local namespace for its local variables; a module has a global namespace for its global variables; etc.  Users absolutely will use these namespaces -- you will create your own variables, classes, functions, etc..  What it's saying is that you shouldn't make up new magic-looking names and put them in your namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

User-controlled namespaces are namespaces like global variables or object attributes. A Python programmer can put whatever names he or she so chooses into those namespaces; community disapproval can't stop it. Double-dunder names like `__init__` and `__file__` live in those namespaces along with ordinary names defined by programmers. The PEP 8 recommendation is that users not create non-standard names that look like the standard magic names.